Episode of Casualty from early 2000s: man gets injured by combat robot
This might be a bit of a longshot, but if anyone can help me track down this episode, it's this place.
This was an episode of Casualty that aired between about 2000-2004, back when Robot Wars was at the height of its popularity here in the UK. One of the "Injuries of the Week" was a man who was building his own combat robot in his shed. I distinctly remember that the robot was green, wedge-shaped, and had a face painted on the front with a circular saw sticking out of its mouth. In fact, it looked rather like this actual Robot Wars competitor:

...but with a circular saw instead of a lifting arm.
The man's injury came when the robot suddenly drove forward and sliced his leg open. I also distinctively remember the man's shed blowing up, though I don't know whether he was still inside it at the time (I might even be misremembering the explosion entirely).
A simple Google search didn't turn up anything relevant. There's an episode list on IMDB, but hardly any of the episodes from that era have descriptions and the titles alone aren't enough for me to be able to tell which episode it is. A lot of them seem to be on YouTube, but none of them have descriptions there either, and I'd rather not have to go through and watch all 100+ of them - that would be my absolute last resort. I am, at least, certain that this was Casualty.
So: Can anyone help me to identify this episode? At the very least, does anyone else remember it, and I'm not going crazy? Thanks in advance!

The only episode I could find mentioning a leg injury, by saw is:
Season 22 Episode 612 "Take it Back" (S22E22) 
This episode aired in 19 January 2008. As Wikipedia says in the description:

Meanwhile in a car workshop a man severs an artery in his leg with a power saw.


Another mention to a saw is in:
Season 29 Episode 902 "Carrot Not Stick" (S29E35) 

Fletch treats a tree cutting's manager after he is crushed by a heavy branch and has a chainsaw dropped just inches from his head.

Which does not match the description you made though.

I searched every season and no mention to robots were made. But I can easily have missed something. It is true that no much information exists for that period. Both IMDB and Wikipedia has a gap on the description at the particular period you are looking for.  
I will keep looking and update my answer, but for the time here is a website with description of each episode. (Just change the number in the URL to go to the next season).
http://www.holby.tv/past-series-casualty/series-14-past-cast/

Good find with Holby.TV! It looks very comprehensive! I've have a quick browse through it myself and see if I can find anything.

The only problem is that the description focuses more in the relationships between the cast rather than the medical cases.

Yeah, it doesn't seem to have anything on the patients from around Series 17/18 onwards. I'll take a look at that Series 22 episode when I get the chance, maybe that's it after all.
